# SQL Report with conditional output

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have the following code and I can't seem to get the correct outcome

```
=IIf
((IsNothing(Fields!db1.Value) OR (Fields!db1.Value = 0)) AND 
(IsNothing(Fields!db2.Value) OR (Fields!db2.Value = 0)), "None", 
IIF(Fields!db1.Value = 1 And Fields!db2.Value = 0, "A",
IIF(Fields!db1.Value = 0 And Fields!db2.Value = 1, "B","A & B")))
```

basically here is what I want:

- If DB1 is null or equal to zero and DB2 is null or equal to zero to output none
- But if DB1 is equal to 1 and DB2 is equal to 0 to output "A",
- But id Db1 is equal to 0 and DB2 is equal to 1 then output "B",
- Lastly if they are both equal to one output "A & B"

Comment: Thanks Ray for the edits much clearer

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Comment: I keep getting the last result, so in this case "A & B" even when the data is clear that it should be "A" or "B"

Comment: Can you add a textbox on your report with the values of db1 and db2 to see what is returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was me not recognising that the datatype coming back that I was checking as an numerical value was coming back as a char so I should have been checking for "0" or "1" in quotes all sorted thanks for your comments peoples